# Can't get my sort function to use print method to show iterations

Tags: c++

I want displayArray on line 69 to work every time it iterates to show the changes of the insertion sort. I haven't been able to get it to work and have been spinning my wheels for a bit. Please help/explain. Thank you in advance.
This is what my output should look like:

**Expected Output**:

```
Enter up to 20 nonnegative whole numbers.
Mark the end of the list with a negative number.
3 7 4 9 5 2 6 1 -1
3 7 4 9 5 2 6 1
3 4 7 9 5 2 6 1
3 4 7 9 5 2 6 1
3 4 5 7 9 2 6 1
2 3 4 5 7 9 6 1
2 3 4 5 6 7 9 1
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9
```

In sorted order the numbers are:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9
```

---

**Code**:

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int MAX_SIZE = 20;

// Fills the array a[] with data from the user for a[0] through a[numberUsed -1].
// Since the user will not necessarily use up all the allocated entries in the array,
// the function will set the actual number of entries used in the "numberUsed"
// reference variable.
void fillArray(int a[], int arraySize, int& numberUsed);

// Sorts the array a[] such that a[0] <= a[1] <= ... <= a[numberUsed - 1].
void insert_sort(int a[], int numberUsed);

// Interchanges the values of v1 and v2.
void swapValues(int& v1, int& v2);

// Displays the contents of the array
void displayArray(const int a[], int numberUsed);


int main( )
{
    cout << "This program sorts numbers from lowest to highest.\n";

    int sampleArray[MAX_SIZE] = {0};
    int numberUsed = 0;


    fillArray(sampleArray, MAX_SIZE, numberUsed);
    insert_sort(sampleArray, numberUsed);

    cout << "In sorted order the numbers are:\n";
    displayArray(sampleArray, numberUsed);

    return 0;
}

void fillArray(int a[], int arraySize, int& numberUsed)
{
    cout << "Enter up to " << arraySize << " nonnegative whole numbers.\n"
    << "Mark the end of the list with a negative number.\n";
    int next  = 0;
    int index = 0;

    cin >> next;

    while ((next >= 0) && (index < arraySize))
    {
        a[index] = next;
        index++;
        cin >> next;
    }

    numberUsed = index;
}

void insertion_sort (int a[], int numberUsed){
    int j, temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberUsed; i++){
        j = i;
        while (j > 0 && a[j] < a[j-1]){
            temp = a[j];
            a[j] = a[j-1];
            a[j-1] = temp;
            j--;
        }
        displayArray(a,numberUsed);
    }
}


void swapValues(int& v1, int& v2)
{
    int temp;
    temp = v1;
    v1   = v2;
    v2   = temp;
}

void displayArray(const int a[], int numberUsed)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < numberUsed; index++)
    {
        cout << a[index] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: And where is your code...?

Comment: sorry was having some trouble with the formatting.

Comment: did you try to compile it?

Comment: Where is method `insertion_sort` called?

Comment: Yeah it works, at least at sorting, but I need to print each change in the array while it is sorted. I think I am calling the function wrong or...

Comment: Ah that is a problem... now I am really lost. Insertion sort and sort array are supposed to be the same thing I think. I need displayArray to work in Insertion_sort

Comment: I think I have done this, but with sort array to insertion_sort instead. It still does not print the iterations. Thank you for pointing that out, you and steve already helped me catch one problem.

Comment: And you changed the name to `insert_sort`, but the implementation is with the name of `insertion_sort`

Comment: Sorry first time here. I won't change it again, but I am gonna let that one stay since it wasn't the issue I made the topic about.

Comment: see this code. http://ideone.com/QcpOaZ

Comment: ok I changed it to match, still not printing the steps the sorting method makes. how do I post the updated code without editing? I am hitting a character length problem in the comment box

Comment: Did you see this code? http://ideone.com/QcpOaZ I think it prints the expected output.

Comment: It does, but I tried to edit mine to be like yours and I am still missing something. I should be able to find it at this point, but I am pretty tilted. Here I will try posting the way you described one moment. Thank you again for all the help, if you don't want to look at what I got now I am still very grateful.

Comment: Your new code's output is pretty much the same with the one I shared with you.

Comment: Can you post the actual output you're getting?

Comment: really, when I run it it, it only prints the final array

Comment: This program sorts numbers from lowest to highest.
Enter up to 20 nonnegative whole numbers.
Mark the end of the list with a negative number.
7 8 9 5 4 5 2 47 8 5 -8
In sorted order the numbers are:
2 4 5 5 5 7 8 8 9 47

Comment: See, http://ideone.com/ZV775W, this is your new code and it prints the expected output.

Comment: yeah I just posted it to that site and it came out fine.  Must be something with my compiler settings or something... weird.

Comment: It's running on my VS 2015 just fine.

Comment: I use eclipse neon and it was acting funky when I started the project. I guess there is a bug associated with the minigw that might be related? W/e the codes good, just tried it on another online compiler site. You are the Man thank you so Much!